# How to link to YouTube videos with thumbnails?

Tags: plugins, thumbnails, youtube

I am brand new to WordPress and find it very confusing. I have a small blog and cannot find a way to easily add a small grid of YouTube thumbnails that link to those videos.

I have looked at all kinds of YouTube plugins (Video Thumbnails, YouTube Gallery, etc), but all of them seem focused on providing tools for the video creators.

I just want a simple table/grid of 3-5 equally-sized cells, displaying the thumbnail and title of a YouTube video, and for the image to be a link to the said video.

Is there a plugin for this? Or do I need to write the HTML myself?

*Just to be clear: I am not referring to Post Thumbnails, but a grid or table of thumbnails within the actual page or post.*

Comment: Googling "wordpress video grid" or "video gallery" seems to offer a number of options that seem suitable.   Judging by screenshots they do exactly that - a grid of video thumbnails.  Of course coding the hml and css yourself might be simpler in the long run if it is a one off requirement.

Comment: @anmari - Most of what I can find is again aimed at video creators. They seem to focus on videos uploaded by the WordPress admin. I only want to  link to other videos.

Comment: This plugin will help you achieve what you want - https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-playlist-player/ - but you can also add static images and link them to the YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of some popular video grid plugins you can use without custom coding. You can create a grid of YouTube thumbnails that link to those videos.

1. [Gallery by Robo – Responsive Photo Image Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/robo-gallery/)
2. [YouTube Gallery – Best YouTube Video Gallery for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-showcase/)
3. [YourChannel: YouTube channel on your website](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yourchannel/)

Good luck!